# Can you make a block appear only in a specific content-type

Tags: blocks, nodes

The natural option is to filter blocks by node ID's. I am looking for a way to filter it by content-types (i.e the block "roses in special prices!" will appear only at the content type "Flowers").

Google search didn't help me very much in this subject. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the block configuration page, select the content type like this picture:

[image]

Comment: Hi, must ask - Can this filtering type create content-duplication and hence risk SEO? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I didn't understand what exactly you meant, what do you mean by `risk SEO`?

Comment: Can the content of the block considered "duplicated content" by Google bots?, I'm thinking it is because It is actually comprised of 2 long columns with much text... If it was 4 boxes of some 4-5 words each I wouldn't even think it this direction of Content-duplication \ Risking SEO, but in this case I assume it is likely... Would glad to know what you think of this, if anything.

Thanks man,

Comment: @benos I always use xml site map module. This module creates a list of pages of the site and submit it to the search engine. Two different links means two different content, But I'm not sure how do search engines treat the duplicated content.